# On Django, how to connect to MySQL database on remote server through SSH?

Tags: mysql, django, database, ssh, remote-server

I've looked around, and can't find any answers that specifically address what I'm wondering:

In the Mac terminal, I can access a remote server through ssh:

```
ssh [my_username]@[server.host.com]
```

which prompts me for a password, and after I enter my password, it brings me to the remote server.

Once I've logged into the remote server, I can access MySQL:

```
mysql -u [other_username] -h [mysql.host.com] -p
```

which prompts me for another password, and after entering the password, I'm in the MySQL console and can show databases located there, etc. We can call the database I'm interested in [database].

My question is, how do I hook up Django, run on my localhost, to [database], so that my app uses that [database]?

Answer (score 8):

You can create an ssh tunnel to map the remote server mysql port to a local port on your machine.

```
ssh -L 3333:127.0.0.1:<remote mysql port> <username>@<remote host> -N
```

Whiles this process is active the local port 3333 will connect to the remote port on the remote host.

Comment: Good answer, and this should work. But I'd be concerned whether this is a good idea for other than testing and non-production purposes.

Comment: I would not use this in production. In production I would setup the appropriate network routes, firewall, etc so that the application server can connect directly to the database server.

Comment: This also works even without the -N flag. Also, you can do away with the <username>@<remote host> by inputting the host name specified in your config file

Comment: How would you put this in the `DATABASE` configuration of `settings.py`?  Is that where you put it?  This seems like a common thing to want to do and can't find much info about it